# How to model a database structure for a booking business domain?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm working on a MySQL “database-driven” booking application but my brain can't seem to work through how to “normalize” the database for what I'm trying to accomplish (nor have I been able to discover anyone else posting about running into a similar hurdle after a week of searching).

My aim of “normalizing” (i.e., modeling) it while I create it is to maximize performance once it gets put into production.

## Business Rules

Expanding on rathishDBA's assumption of business rules please note that, in fact, the business rules are as follows:

- Each room may contain zero or more pieces of equipment (zero-to-many).
- Each user can book one or more bookings (one-to-many).
- Each booking belongs to exactly one user (one-to-one).
- Each booking contains exactly one set (set in this context being defined as one user, one room, and one time slot).
- Each booking's `start` in Room A must be **greater than or equal to** the `end` of another booking in Room A.
- Each booking's `end` in Room A must be **less than or equal to** the `start` of another booking in Room A.
- Each booking's `usercount` must be less than or equal to the room's `maxcapacity`

## Functional Dependencies

roomnumber → (maxcapacity, equipment)

(userid, roomnumber, usercount, start, end) → calendarid

maxcapacity → usercount

## Current Structure

In order to meet requirements, I created four tables (`configurations` is used to determine which room has what equipment):

```
CREATE TABLE rooms (
`roomid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`roomnumber` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`maxcapacity` INT NOT NULL, -- maximum number of people allowed in the room
PRIMARY KEY (roomid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE roomequipment (
`equipmentid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`equipmentname` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (equipmentid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE configurations (
`configurationid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`roomid` INT NOT NULL,
`equipmentid` INT,
PRIMARY KEY (configurationid),
CONSTRAINT FK_RoomId FOREIGN KEY (roomid) REFERENCES rooms(roomid),
CONSTRAINT FK_EquipmentId FOREIGN KEY (equipmentid) REFERENCES roomequipment(equipmentid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE calendar (
`calendarid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`configurationid` INT NOT NULL,
`userid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`usercount` INT NOT NULL, -- number of people attending booking
`start` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`end` DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (calendarid),
CONSTRAINT calendar_icfk FOREIGN KEY (configurationid) REFERENCES configurations(configurationid),
CONSTRAINT calendar_ibfk FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users(userid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The problem I'm running into with the way my tables are structured is that if a select query by `roomnumber` to get results listing what equipment is in a specified room I don't know how I should have it structured without violating Normal Forms.

I have the rest of the database functional but the last goal is to structure the database in a way that a user can add a new piece of equipment to `roomequipment` arbitrarily but I have no clue how to accomplish this without results such as duplicate rows of `roomnumber` or storing configurations in something like a CLOB XML attribute.

## Sample Data

To expand upon my question, some sample data to further explain:

```
INSERT INTO rooms 
    (roomnumber, maxcapacity) 
VALUES 
    ('Board Room', 30);

INSERT INTO roomequipment 
    (equipmentname) 
VALUES 
    ('projector');

INSERT INTO configurations 
    (roomid, equipmentid) 
VALUES 
    ((SELECT roomid 
        FROM rooms 
       WHERE roomnumber = 'Board Room'),
     (SELECT equipmentid 
        FROM roomequipment 
       WHERE equipmentname = 'projector'));
```

## Application Workflow

To clarify the context of this question, but as an aside from the database structure definition, the application workflow is as follows:

1. A user is presented with a room availability search form.
2. The search form has fields for *start time*, *end time*, *capacity (max capacity)*, and *equipment*.
3. When the user submits the form, the intention is for the database to be queried and return a list of available (non-booked) rooms. The user then selects the room they wish to book from a displayed list (each list item will show room name, max capacity, and available equipment).
4. After a specified room is selected the user clicks submit and the booking information (designated room, user, start date, end date) should be saved.

**Note:** One of my biggest concerns would be a race condition if two or more users attempt to book the same room with *identical or overlapping times*.

## Question

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be totally wrong since I don't fully understand your business, but I'll lay out some ideas anyhow.

When modelling entities I would stay away from adding auto-generated keys in each and every table. At a later time that can be done if necessary, but to get a feeling af how things relate I would start with natural keys.

If I get it right your calendar table represents bookings and I would use that identifier. A user can book a room with zero or more equipment. This would lead me into something like:

```
CREATE TABLE bookings 
( userid INT NOT NULL
, roomid INT NOT NULL
, start DATETIME NOT NULL
, end DATETIME NOT NULL
,     PRIMARY KEY (userid, roomid, start)
, CONSTRAINT calendar_icfk FOREIGN KEY (roomid) 
      REFERENCES rooms(roomid),
, CONSTRAINT calendar_ibfk FOREIGN KEY (userid) 
      REFERENCES users(userid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

How does the equipment fit into the picture? If the equipment for a room is rather static, I would add equipment to the room:

```
CREATE TABLE equipment
( equipmentid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, equipmentname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,   PRIMARY KEY (equipmentid)    
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE roomequipment 
( roomid INT NOT NULL
, equipmentid INT NOT NULL
,   PRIMARY KEY (roomid, equipmentid)
, ... foreign keys to rooms and equipment
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

If on the other hand, the equipment for a room varies from booking to booking, I would relate equipment with the booking:

```
CREATE TABLE bookingequipments
( userid INT NOT NULL
, roomid INT NOT NULL
, start DATETIME NOT NULL
, equipmentid INT NOT NULL
,     PRIMARY KEY (userid, roomid, start, equipmentid)
, CONSTRAINT calendar_icfk FOREIGN KEY (userid, roomid, start) 
      REFERENCES bookings(userid, roomid, start),
, CONSTRAINT calendar_ibfk FOREIGN KEY (equipmentid) 
      REFERENCES equipment(equipmentid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

In both cases, the USER books a room.

If you decide to introduce a surrogate key in for example bookings:

```
CREATE TABLE bookings 
( bookingid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, userid INT NOT NULL
, roomid INT NOT NULL
, start DATETIME NOT NULL
, end DATETIME NOT NULL
,     PRIMARY KEY (bookingid)
```

don't throw away the candidate key you identified, make that a UNIQUE constraint:

```
,     UNIQUE (userid, roomid, start)

, CONSTRAINT calendar_icfk FOREIGN KEY (roomid) 
      REFERENCES rooms(roomid),
, CONSTRAINT calendar_ibfk FOREIGN KEY (userid) 
      REFERENCES users(userid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

bookingequipment could then be:

```
CREATE TABLE bookingequipments
( bookingid INT NOT NULL
, equipmentid INT NOT NULL
,     PRIMARY KEY (bookingid, equipmentid)
, CONSTRAINT calendar_icfk FOREIGN KEY (bookingid) 
      REFERENCES bookings(bookingid),
, CONSTRAINT calendar_ibfk FOREIGN KEY (equipmentid) 
      REFERENCES equipment(equipmentid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

When to introduce a surrogate key is almost a religious issue, some people will tell you to always use them, other to never use them. Personally, I try to decide from case to case. The criteria I use:

A key should ideally be all of the following:

```
* unique -- obvious
* simple -- to many attributes is a bad thing, how many is too many?
* familiar -- can be used to identify something outside of the database
* irreducible -- no subset of the key should be a key
* stable -- should not change on a regular basis
```

In many situations there will be a conflict between these criteria and one will have to sacrifice one or more of these.

As mentioned I don't know your business, hopefully, you will get some ideas from my post anyhow.

As a side note, your INSERT statement can be written as:

```
 INSERT INTO configurations (roomid, equipmentid) 
 SELECT r.roomid, e.equipmentid 
 FROM rooms as r
 CROSS JOIN equipments as e
 WHERE roomnumber = 'Board Room'
   AND equipmentname = 'projector';
```

or by using an old comma join:

```
 INSERT INTO configurations (roomid, equipmentid) 
 SELECT r.roomid, e.equipmentid 
 FROM rooms as r, equipments as e
 WHERE roomnumber = 'Board Room'
   AND equipmentname = 'projector';
```

You can think of VALUES as a table constructor in OO terms, it is only needed when you want to insert literal values only:

```
 INSERT INTO configurations (roomid, equipmentid)
 VALUES (1,34);
```

If you are inserting the result of a select, you can add literals in the select:

```
 INSERT INTO configurations (roomid, equipmentid)
 SELECT roomid, 34
 FROM rooms
 WHERE roomnumber = 'Board Room';
```

EDIT: Temporal constraints

In SQL2011 support for temporal constraints were added to the standard, several DBMS:s implement at least part of this. You could then implement your business rules:

- Each booking's start in Room A must be greater than or equal to the end of another booking in Room A.
- Each booking's end in Room A must be less than or equal to the start of another booking in Room A.

like:

```
CREATE TABLE bookings 
( bookingid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, userid INT NOT NULL
, roomid INT NOT NULL
, start DATETIME NOT NULL
, end DATETIME NOT NULL
,     PRIMARY KEY (bookingid)

,   PERIOD BUSINESS_TIME (start, end)
,   UNIQUE (roomid, business_time without overlaps) );
```

But as far as I know this is not implemented in the latest version of MySQL yet.

Instead, you can use validation triggers to enforce this at the DBMS level (untested):

```
DELIMITER @
CREATE TRIGGER validate_room_period
BEFORE INSERT ON bookings 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
      IF (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM bookings
          WHERE (NEW.BEGIN <= BEGIN AND NEW.END >= BEGIN)
             OR (NEW.END <= END AND NEW.END >= END) 
         ) > 0
      THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '77000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Room already booked during this period';
      END IF;
END @
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I have updated the original question to include the specific application workflow and a list of business rules which I had not previously included.

Comment: So, you can NOT book an empty room any more?

Comment: After additional testing, the answer you provided is fantastic and works fantastically! Thank you for your thorough explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I may not capture your complete requirement, without knowing exact and whole requirements we cannot design a complete data model. Let us assume the following business rules:

- Each Room may contains one or more equipments.
- Each equipments may belongs to one or more rooms.
- Each user can book one or many bookings.
- Each booking should belongs to at least one user.
- Each booking may contains one or more user configurations.
- Each configuration must belongs to at least one booking.
- Each configuration belongs to one or more user configuration (A user may book multiple rooms with different configurations under same bookings).
- Each user configuration must contains at least one Configuration.

For the above rules, the **Logical data model** would be as follows:

[image: Hotel Booking]

Based on your exact requirements, the design may change. Please look [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125248/21119) for similar data model. [Check here](http://www.rathishkumar.in/2015/12/conceptual-data-model.html) to know more about conceptual data model. I hope it may help you.

**EDIT 1**

**Configuration** - `Associative table` - Many to Many relationship between the `Room and Equipment`.

**UserConf** - `Associative table` - Many to Many relationship between the `User and Configuration.`

User can book more than one room with different equipments under same Booking. Room with same/different equipments may booked in many bookings on different period of time. The `UserConf associative table` is used to capture the rooms with different configuration under same booking by a user (it depends - business may not have this requirement). I hope it may help.

**EDIT 2**

Based on the business rules, I have modified the model little bit.

[image]

**"to get results listing what equipment is in a specified room"**

You can get the equipment list available in specific room by using the configuration table JOIN with the equipment table.

```
SELECT C.equipment_name 
FROM 
configuration A 
INNER JOIN room B
ON
A.room_id = B.room_id
INNER JOIN equipment C
ON
A.quipment_id = C.equipment_id;
```

I hope this may help you.Thanks!!!

Comment: Two questions. 1) In your model why is there a UserConf AND a Configuration table? 2) Would you mind editing your answer to include boilerplate SQL for this model? That might help me understand. Thank you!

Comment: I have updated the original question to include the specific application workflow and a list of business rules which I had not previously included.